# Is it harmful to install a lighter desktop environtment (XFCE) on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: unity, 14.04, xfce

I am to install Xfce, because the default (unity desktop) on ubuntu 14.04 runs pretty slow on my lenovo z570 laptop. Is it really recommended to keep the default desktop environment ?
I googled a little bit for the answer and found [this](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/fatalmistakes#TOC-Don-t-mix-desktop-environments:-stick-to-the-default).

So my question is, is it (in any way) a harm to the computer, if I install xfce desktop alongside unity ?

Comment: My experience is that it will work pretty well, but complete removal is difficult.

Comment: No, not unless you get really tired of it.  You switch between desktops at the login screen, and can effectively ignore the other DE's, except that they also add their mix of programs to the default of Ubuntu.  Some good stuff in there.

Comment: you can expect to install anything from the repositories without a serious problem. With multiple DE you sometimes have what are considered cosmetic issues, all of which you can configure. If you have a problem, ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 2):

You can expect to install anything from the repositories without a serious problem. With multiple DE you sometimes have what are considered cosmetic issues, all of which you can configure.

Of course, some people find these "cosmetic" issues more or less annoying, but, they will not prevent the applications or system from working.

Each DE tends to have a set of applications for editing, multi media, etc so you will end up with duplicate applications.

All of the basic applications will work on any DE or WM. The only real conflict is that you can run only one WM at a time (so you can not run kwin at the same time as unity).

In the event you have a problem, ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm kinda new to Ubuntu, I've been using it for 2 months now and I already tried out other DEs. Few weeks ago I installed Cinnamon and it worked perfectly fine, didn't slow down my laptop. Also today I installed Gnome and till now I feel like it's even faster than 14.04s Unity.
So I would say that there's no need to worry.

Comment: thanks. Well, my another question is,If I install a new desktop environment, Will I still be able to use my existing applications in the same way as I do in unity DE?

Comment: sure. I didn't have any application which doesn't worked after I changed my DE.

Answer (score 0):

Nope! No problem at all!

I actually much prefer the XFCE environment even on my smokin' fast computer - it's pretty solid.